# How to Utilize migrations in Asp.net core With MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-query

I have an ASP.NET core application that utilize mongodb as Database. I want to change the columns Name and same work as we do in Code First Approach with SQL. Please guide How we can achieve this

Comment: I don't follow how this relates to ASP.NET Core? Perhaps you're using Entity Framework?

Comment: i've written a [library](https://mongodb-entities.com/wiki/Data-Migrations.html) that can do progressive migrations similar to EF. you can use it in conjuction with mongodb driver.

Comment: No, Its not Entity Framework. I'm using C# mongoDb driver